# Macintosh shortcuts and tools

Tags: mac, macos

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Mac OS: Tips & Tricks for Programmers/Geeks.](https://superuser.com/questions/74648/mac-os-tips-tricks-for-programmers-geeks)
>   [Useful keyboard shortcuts on a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/138365/useful-keyboard-shortcuts-on-a-mac)

what are your favorite Macintosh keyboard shortcuts and tools?

Comment: Another duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/138365/useful-keyboard-shortcuts-on-a-mac

Answer (score 1):

[TextExpander](http://www.smileonmymac.com/TextExpander/) for inserting text, graphics, or anything else that can be stored on the clipboard.  [Quicksilver](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/14831/quicksilver) for keyboard shortcuts that launch programs or do other system functions.

Answer (score 0):

TextExpander by a long way. More for boilerplate text and standard references so I don't have to look them up, I just type in the shortcut I've assigned. It saves me hours.